# How to Use .srt files as the input files for Google Cloud text-to-speech or Amazon Polly?

Tags: google-cloud-speech, google-text-to-speech, amazon-polly

I've got videos with English subtitles/transcripts as ".srt" files that I want to use Google Cloud text-to-speech or Amazon Polly for to generate voiceovers.
Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Try convert to SSML